# I Want to detect users location via google map api

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-maps, geolocation

Before I ask a question, I want to apologize if I can't properly ask a question because I'm new at this community.

Recently I'm launching my site for restaurant, So, I want to detect users location for home deliveries.

**here is my site**  https://gharkakhana.online/ it's a wordpress based site, I have integrated the map, but find my location button is not detecting the users location, maybe .btn geo-location class is not working.

I Really feel good if somone help me out!

Answer (score 0):

The user has to give permission either in the device or browser, for your application to be able to detect device locations.

Google maps API don't support seeing location.

Refer for browsers:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation_API

For Android:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/overview

Comment: yeah i know but after giving the permission API don't detect the users location.
Please go to [link](https://gharkakhana.online/) give the permission and check what's the problem?